# Get sales per hour

Tags: mysql, datetime, aggregate

I want to get the number of sales per hour in a specific date:

```
table : invoices
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+
|   id  |   name    |   amout   |       date               |
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+
|   1   |   John    |   12313   |   2017-05-20 13:50:08    |
|   2   |   Mary    |    5335   |   2017-05-17 22:21:35    |
|   3   |   Jeff    |      23   |   2017-05-17 22:32:13    |
|   4   |   Bill    |     132   |   2017-05-17 23:25:55    |
|   5   |   Bob     |     853   |   2017-05-17 24:52:37    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+
```

So, I want to get this output:

```
9 a.m. to 10 a.m. we generated X invoices.
10 a.m. to 11 a.m. we generated Y invoices.
11 a.m. to 12 a.m. we generated Z invoices.
```

- X,Y and Z it's the number of invoices generated in these interval.

How I can do that? I use MySQL.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read this. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056  Without knowing what your tables look like it's difficult guesswork to answer your question.

Comment: sorry, I just added the table

Comment: First step is to try something. Show an effort, and if something's not working, we can help.

Comment: Of course, I tried with this:
`SELECT COUNT(id) total FROM invoices WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-05-20 13:00:00' AND '2017-05-20 13:59:59';`
But with this form, I need to create a different query for each hour of the day... So, I want to know if there's any way to get the total of each hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three SQL concepts will help you get an answer to this question.

1. "Truncating" a datestamp; that is, extracting the hour from it. For example, `2017-05-27 14:37.20` is truncated to `2017-05-27 14:00:00`.
2. Selecting rows from your table with datestamps on a particular day.
3. Using `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`.

You can truncate like this.

```
     SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%y-%m-%d %H:00:00') hour_starting
       FROM invoices
```

You can add to that query to select rows for a particular date like this

```
     SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%y-%m-%d %H:00:00') hour_starting
       FROM invoices
      WHERE `date` >= '2017-05-27` 
        AND `date` < '2017-05-27' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Notice that this chooses all rows with date values on or after (`>=`) midnight on `2017-05-27`. and before but not including (`<`) midnight on the next day.

Finally, you can use COUNT like this.

```
     SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%y-%m-%d %H:00:00') hour_starting,
            COUNT(*) invoice_count
       FROM invoices
      WHERE `date` >= '2017-05-27` 
        AND `date` < '2017-05-27' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
      GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

Comment: Date isn't a reserved word - just sayin'